# How to test if else condition in rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to RSpec and I want to test the if-else condition of a controller, I searched on the internet but couldn't find results properly.

```
  def edit
    if @question.user_id == current_user.id
      render :edit
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I am using rails 6
Please guide me that how do I write RSpec for this condition, with the help of an example.

Comment: Make two scenarios and mock the question with two different user. it will run for both the condition

Comment: You, or someone else, asked *exactly* this question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579449/how-to-write-test-case-using-rspec-for-this-action#comment115947123_65579449

Answer (score 1):

To test this out in RSpec you need to manipulate the parameters that are pass to the controller to generate the variables on the condition`@question.user_id == current_user.id`.

usually in rspec you would have something like this to all the controller usually inclosed with a before action

```
before do
 get :edit, params
end
```

The `params` you pass in should vary based on the conditions you want to test.